# Linux issues with cp: -r not specified; omitting directory

Tags: linux, cp

Can someone help me understand what that means?

```
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory
```

I am trying to use this command

```
sudo cp /home/$USER/Documents/myfile.10 /home
```

Error:

```
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/home/administrator/Documents/myfile.10'
```

What does it mean? Why did it happen? What can I do about it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please restrict to one question per question: either `cp` issue or the other. Asking for a test script without showing your research effort is not a good question; we are not a script writing service. If I were you I would get rid of this "Also ..." part ([edit] the question).

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question to meet our standards. If you need help with LDAP (which is a separate issue) then please ask a new question. Your original question is archived [here](https://superuser.com/revisions/1418605/1), in case you want to copy from it. You should take our [tour] and see [ask] first. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/home/administrator/Documents/myfile.10'
> ```

This means `myfile.10` is a directory. `cp` won't copy it, unless you explicitly use `-r` (or equivalent) flag.

For `cp` in my Debian these are equivalent: `-r`, `-R`, `--recursive`. POSIX, however defines `-R` only (`-r` is mentioned as obsolescent). [It says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html):

> If *source_file* is of type directory, the following steps shall be taken:
>
> - If the `-R` option was not specified, `cp` shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, do nothing more with *source_file*, and go on to any remaining files.
>
> [...]

The conclusion is your `cp` does exactly what it's supposed to do. If you want to copy the whole directory, use `-R`. If you expected `myfile.10` to be a non-directory then you need to investigate why the discrepancy.